# Action based upon optional argument in \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments

With the following environment, I would like to make `#3` an optional argument.  In a way that when `#3` is present, the text starts on the next line.  And when `#3` is missing, the text is written in the adjacent area as done by the theorem environment.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Pz}{mmm}
  %% General Proposition
  %% \Pz {SPECIFIER} {LOCATOR} {TITLE}
  { \noindent #1 \ #2 \ (#3) }
  {}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter {This is an introduction
  to some topic}

\section{Some Section}

This section is about this and that.

\begin{Pz}{Theorem}{GCHQ}{Pythagoras}
  Some Text
\end{Pz}

\begin{Pz}{Theorem}{GCHQ}
  Some Text on new line
\end{Pz}

\end{document}
```

The following is not doing the trick

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Pz}{mmO{}}
  %% General Proposition
  %% \wvPz {SPECIFIER} {LOCATOR} {TITLE}
  %% TITLE Optional, Default Empty
  { \noindent #1 \ #2 \ (#3)
    \IfValueT {#3} { \newline }
  }
  {}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo The bulk of the `xparse` documentation is now incorporated into `usrguide`.

Comment: Great, what's `usrguide`?  I couldn't find it in CTAN and MikTeX.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `texdoc usrguide` doesn't bring it up? (Maybe MikTeX doesn't install documentation by default?)  It's part of the kernel documentation (the user version of `clsguide`, which is for package writers).

Comment: Okay, I found it in `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\doc\latex\base`

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include code that was provided (in this case indirectly) by the answer. It makes the original question hard to understand, and it makes it appear that the question wasn't answered as asked, when in fact it was in this case.

Comment: @AlanMunn Which edit are you referring to? As far as I can tell, the most recent edit was extremely minor and didn't touch any code. I'm not clear about the order of earlier edits in relation to your answer, though.

Comment: @cfr The edit that included the code that wasn't doing the trick.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh. I had thought your answer was in response to that version originally. But the time stamps are the same at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this. Optional arguments are represented by the `o` specifier, (or `O{default}` if you want an optional argument with a default value. You can then test whether the argument was provided by using the `\IfNoValueTF{no arg}{arg}` test, or one of its alternatives.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Pz}{mmo}
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\noindent #1 \ #2  }%
    {\noindent  #1 \ #2 \ (#3)\par}%
    }
    {}
\begin{document}

\begin{Pz}{Theorem}{GCHQ}[Pythagoras]
  Some Text
\end{Pz} 

\begin{Pz}{Theorem}{GCHQ}  Some Text
\end{Pz} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Like that.  Would not have guessed that I needed a repetition of the command for both true and false.

Comment: There are other ways to write the code, but IMO this is cleaner and more readable even if it involves a little repetition. For example, you could also use `{\noindent #1 \ #2 \IfNoValueF{#3}{\ (#3)\par}}` as the begin environment code which would remove the repetition. If this is more readable to you, then you can do that.

Comment: For some reason `\begin{Pz}{Pz}{ID}{TITLE}` does not show `(TITLE}`.  I only get `TITLE`.

Comment: @Raksh Optional arguments are introduced by square brackets, `[]` not braces `{}`.

Comment: Right.  It works good now that I have changed it.

Comment: @Raksh Do you actually have code for ending the environment in your real document? Because otherwise, you could just use a command instead. Using an environment will automatically group things, however, whereas a command wouldn't do that. So if you might define or change things locally or do something like `\color{green} ...`, the environment is probably more convenient.

Comment: Or you might have an editor, like mine, which deals better with environments than commands ....

Comment: @cfr Yes, I have similar misgivings about this environment. Because in general I don't think it's a good idea to have environments with arguments; they should conceptually be containers for stuff, although I'm sure there are places where arguments are appropriate.

Comment: Have included `\noindent` after `\par`.  But I still can see a space before the text starts.  Is this because of some environment property?

Comment: @AlanMunn I'd consider that a bit extreme, personally. However, I'm not keen on environments with more than one argument, especially since you can always use a key-value interface. (I don't like the fact `prooftrees` has an environment with a mandatory argument, but I couldn't find a way around it.)

Comment: @Raksh Do you mean space you don't see in Alan's output above? Are you referring to horizontal or vertical space? It's not because it's an environment.

Comment: @Raksh my crystal ball tells me that you moved the `\noindent` inside of the definition of your environment. If you do that the paragraph starts there, and the space you have after your closing `]` is no longer ignored. You can fix that by putting an `\ignorespaces` after your `\noindent`. If your environment now would start with a blank line you'd still get something wrong, but I guess that might be fine.

Comment: Yes, I included `\noindent` after `\par` in the environment `Pz`.

Comment: @Skillmon Using `\ignorespaces` fixed the problem.

Comment: I like to indent my code inside an environment clause.

Comment: @Raksh has nothing to do with the indentation of the following line, the line ending after the closing `]` is turned into a space by TeX. Spaces at the start of a line are ignored.

Comment: @Raksh The indentation at the start of the line isn't the problem. It's the line ending after `]` and the uncommented line endings in Alan's code which cause the space when they occur after `\noindent`.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the problem now, but I've added some line ending `%`.