# Environment with multiple optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

I have the following environment taking four arguments, the latter two being optional.  Things look as expected.  Would I have to test for `#4` in my case ?

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Statement}{mmoO{orange}}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#3}
        { \noindent #1 \ #2 \, }
      { \noindent #1 \ #2 \ (#3)
        \vspace{0.1cm} \par \noindent \ignorespaces }
    \color{#4}
  }
  { \vspace{0.3cm} }
```

Comment: is this a continuation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698083/action-based-upon-optional-argument-in-newdocumentenvironment ?

Comment: also you need `%` at ends of lines to avoid adding white space.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to test for `#4` as it's never empty it will always have a value, but you can not change that value from orange without also setting `#3` as you have made the adjacent options `#3` and `#4` both optional.

It would be better to make the color `#1`

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Statement}{O{orange}mmo}
```

Then:

A blue statement with no title

`\begin{Statement}[blue]{aa}{bb}`

A red statement with (title)

`\begin{Statement}[red]{aa}{bb}[title]`

A statement with default color and a title

`\begin{Statement}{aa}{bb}[title]`

---

With this structure the two options can be set independently.